# Understanding memory layout for array and slice

Tags: arrays, go, slice

On a 64 bit OS machine,

For below code:

```
println("Simple Array:")
var arrayint = [...]int{1, 2, 3, 4} //assign
fmt.Println(arrayint)

println("Simple Slice:")
var sliceint []int
sliceint = arrayint[:] //assign
fmt.Println(sliceint)
```

Below is the memory representation:

### [image]

---

For below code:

```
println("Array of arrays:")
var arrayofarrays [3][len(arrayint)]int
for i := range arrayofarrays { //assign
    arrayofarrays[i] = arrayint
}
fmt.Println(arrayofarrays)

println("Array of slices:")
var arrayofslice [len(arrayofarrays)][]int
for i := range arrayofarrays { // assign
    arrayofslice[i] = arrayofarrays[i][:]
}
fmt.Println(arrayofslice)

println("Slice of arrays:")
var sliceofarray [][len(arrayint)]int
sliceofarray = arrayofarrays[:]
fmt.Println(sliceofarray)
```

**Edit:** Below is the memory representation:

### [image]

---

For below code:

```
var sliceofslices [][]int
```

below is the memory representation:

### [image]

---

For below line:

```
sliceofslices = arrayofslice[:]
```

---

What is the memory representation for `sliceofslices`? Need to understand before using it...

Comment: Where do you get the idea that arrays are pointers? I think any confusion here is because arrays are actually values. https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayofslice` is an array of slices, and since size of a slice is 24 bytes, size of `arrayofslice` is n*24, where `n` is the element count. `sliceofslices` is a slice with the backing array `arrayofslice`.

Comment: **1)** Just edited my query.. based on your answer... Please confirm my understanding on `arrayofslice` **2)** Can I say `sliceofslices` is  (pointer, 3, 3)?

Comment: 1) your understanding appears correct, except that arrayofslice is not a pointer pointing to the array, but it *is* the array. 2) correct.

Comment: You mean, there is no separate 8 byte allocated for `arrayint`, `arrayofarrays` & `arrayofslice` to store address, as shown in the query. Is that correct?

Comment: No. an array is a value type. &arrayofarrays is the same as &arrayofarrays[0]

Comment: Am confused, when you say, "No"... Is this the correct understanding, as shown in this link? https://github.com/shamhub/GO_programming/blob/master/training/4_data_structures/memory_layout.png

Comment: The image in the link is correct. The image in the question shows arrayofslices as a pointer to an array, which is not correct.

Comment: An array contains all its elements. When you get an array argument to a function, you get a copy of the array. A slice points to its elements. When you get a slice argument, you get a copy of the slice, not the copy of the elements.

Comment: No it is not. In C, &arr is still the same as &arr[0]. But it is passed as a pointer.

Comment: Trying to practice the usage of array, slice and pointer type by implementing map type. Can you please comment on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61141957/how-to-handle-overflow-issue-in-the-implementation#comment108206739_61141957